# What is the backend difference between "filter_var" and "preg_replace" in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have numbers coming out of a database (very controlled input) that will have underscores before and after them. They are stored like this:

```
_51_ _356_
```

They will not be stored in any other format, but there will be times where I need to get just the numbers out of them. I have chosen to use either

```
$x = filter_var($myNumber, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

or

```
$y = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$myNumber);
```

I am not sure of the nuances between the 2 in the backend, but they both produce exactly what I need (I think so, anyway), so it doesn't matter to me which I use. What are the pros and cons of using each of these options? (For example, does one use an array or other weird thing that I might need to know about? One uses way too many resources?)

Comment: whenever possible try to use string functions over regex ones, ie use str_replace() or trim()

Comment: Benchmark it. The two solutions are completely different. `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` does exactly only what it says. `preg` is a complete regex engine of which you're using a tiny bit of capability. One is probably vastly more efficient than the other, but you can only confirm this through benchmarking.

Comment: Before benchmark it, add the quantifier `+` to have a more efficient pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there isn't big difference in your case. I think `preg_replace` is more expensive in resource, since it had to parse the regex pattern.

Alternatively you can use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
echo trim('_12_', '_');
```

It will remove the '_' in both side, I think this is the most readable manner to do.

Comment: I will look into this trim(). I might just use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Filters don't use regular expressions, but work in a similar way: iterate a string char-by-char and remove characters that don't match the pattern:

```
for (i = 0; i < Z_STRLEN_P(value); i++) {
    if ((*map)[str[i]]) {
        buf[c] = str[i];
        ++c;
    }
}
```

@http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/filter/sanitizing_filters.c#filter_map_apply

and the `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT` is defined as `[^0-9+-]`:

```
/* strip everything [^0-9+-] */
const unsigned char allowed_list[] = "+-" DIGIT;
filter_map     map;

filter_map_init(&map);
filter_map_update(&map, 1, allowed_list);
filter_map_apply(value, &map);
```

@http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/filter/sanitizing_filters.c#php_filter_number_int

Of course, `[^0-9+-]` is not a right expression to filter integer numbers, therefore be prepared for surprises:

```
$x = filter_var("+++123---", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
var_dump($x); // WTF?
```

My suggestion is to stick to regular expressions: they are explicit and far less buggy than filters.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to try some various methods for this, so set up the following benchmark. It looks like for your case, trim is definitely the best option as it only has to look at the beginning and end of the string instead of each character. Here are my test results on 10,000,000 random integers surrounded by underscores running PHP 7.0.18.

preg_replace: 1.9469740390778 seconds.

filter_var: 1.6922700405121 seconds.

str_replace: 0.72129797935486 seconds.

trim: 0.37275195121765 seconds.

And here is my code if anyone wants to run similar tests:

```
<?php
$ints = array();//array_fill(0, 10000000, '_1029384756_');
for($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++) {
$ints[] = '_'.mt_rand().'_';
}

$start = microtime(true);
foreach($ints as $v) {
preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $v);
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo 'preg_replace in '.($end-$start).' seconds.',PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);
foreach($ints as $v) {
filter_var($v, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo 'filter_var in '.($end-$start).' seconds.',PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);
foreach($ints as $v) {
str_replace('_', '', $v);
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo 'str_replace in '.($end-$start).' seconds.',PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);
foreach($ints as $v) {
trim($v, '_');
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo 'trim in '.($end-$start).' seconds.',PHP_EOL;
```